# arcgis server 10.1 site url

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1

should my "site manager" url contain "localhost:6080"? or should it be "(my pc name):6080"? After giving arcgis server account permissions to proper folders I created my site, but it has the name "localhost:6080", will I still be able to link published services with REST Url when making web maps? I am on ags server 10.1.

I have a .com registered and I am making a subdomain at the moment. How do I point my arcgis server to this domain? (the process to making my files accessible outside my network) or do I need a webserver and arcgis for server installed to do what I wish to do?(making web maps accessible to people on the internet). I do not have a web server installed. I am trying to install arcgis for server 10.1 on my windows 7 ultimate machine.

According to Branden, using "http://gis.mycompanywebsite.com/arcgis/rest/services/101/my_service_name/MapServer" Will point my javascript to my services, using this will it matter if I have localhost in my url, if so, how do I avoid having a localhost site?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter as long as you access the Manager from that machine.  In order to access from a different machine you need to use either the fully qualified domain
 (http://mywebdomain.com/arcgis/manager)
or from inside your network the machine name the machine name can be used.
The 6080 is required only when you don't have the web adapter installed.

If you don't have a .com registered you will need to do that.
If your company has a .com you can "if IT will allow" register a sub domain
(they can probably take care of that for you)
like gis.mycompanywebsite.com (the gis is the subdomain part).
Once you have the domain or subdomain you don't need to do anything else (except wait for it to propagate). you will just call that external ip or url in your javascript.
comments are ok but try to keep them to a min.  you can edit your original question with augmented or enhanced information to help the question.

http://gis.mycompanywebsite.com/arcgis/rest/services/101/my_service_name/MapServer

Comment: Thank you Brad! I don't have the web adapter installed, so the 6080 is ok. So if I publish a service and write javascript to load the layer, the rest url with the "localhost:6080" will do the job? I'm trying to display some of my work on my website using arcgis javascript api.

Comment: no localhost is actually a loopback it will only work on the machine that has iis installed. if you want to display it anywhere but that machine you will have to use the machine name (if you only want to access it from inside your network) and a fully qualified url dommain if you want to display it outside your network.

Comment: Well, it seems my current set up is not going to cut it.  Brad, if I want to show off my maps via web maps on my website, how do I go about setting up a "fully qualified url domain"? I never saw an option to use my machine name as my site address or to set up a domain url. Please excuse the simplicity of my questions. I'm very new to ArcGis server. I am very thankful, in a few minutes, I have gotten farther than in 2 full days.

Comment: brandon, could you clarify "you will just call that external ip or url in your javascript."